# Eclipse & NetBeans and using SVN & Maven

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven-2, netbeans6.8, maven-eclipse-plugin

I have an issue, I've created a Maved project with Eclipse, and committed into a SVN repository. from here I tried two approaches:

1. Import the project into NetBeans from the folder of Eclipse workspace.
2. Check the project out of the repository into NetBeans.

in both cases, once I clean and build the project, NetBeans deletes the 'target' folder, thous causing a problem recommitting the project back into the SVN repository.

I have tested this few times on different projects.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added the target folder to svn this is the wrong approach, cause target folder should be ignore by svn (svn:ignore). Cause it can also be deleted by a simple mvn clean